# Creating vector tiles from OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, vector-tiles, osm2vectortiles, mapzen

I need to understand the process of creating Mapbox Vector Tiles from OSM data in some detail -- in particular I need to fiddle with cutting out a lot of data (esp. buildings) to keep the final vector tile sizes down.

So far I have found two repositories that allow the creation of Mapbox Vector Tiles from OSM data:

- Mapzen: https://github.com/tilezen/vector-datasource
- osm2vectortiles: https://github.com/osm2vectortiles/osm2vectortiles

Is there  any information on the differences between these which is likely to be more tractable?

Comment: You may also wish to look at Tilemaker: https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker

Comment: ... or see the OSM wiki about https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles to get a general overview about that topic or even other tools.

Answer (score 3):

- For Mapzen: don't use it as it's for vector tiles 1.0 specification (outdated)
- For osm2vectortiles, don't use  because of legal reasons e.g https://github.com/osm2vectortiles/osm2vectortiles/issues/387#issuecomment-273492760 and instead use OpenMapTiles (it replaces the previous osm2vectortiles) using [this quick recipe](https://github.com/openmaptiles/openmaptiles/blob/master/QUICKSTART.md) if you want to generate your own tiles